Fit ode in R with multiple time series simultaneously
I am a biology student and I am recently learning how to fit ode with observed data in R. I cultivate a microbe under a given condition but with two different initial densities (N0=5 and N0=100), I recorded its densities (N) at sequence of time (10, 20,...200). My data are the following:
# observed data
library(ggplot2)
N0 <- c(5, 200); time <- seq(0, 200, 10)
df <- data.frame(time=rep(time, 2), N0=rep(N0, each=21),                N=c(5.0,12.6,27.9,51.9,74.7,88.7,94.6,98.1,100.3,100.2,99.3,97.8,99.3,97.9,98.7,99.6,99.3,99.1,99.9,99.7,98.1,200.0,123.7,107.5,101.1,99.5,100.7,98.4,99.7,99.4,101.1,99.2,99.2,100.8,99.0,100.0,100.2,99.7,99.3,100.7,99.6,99.7))
ggplot(df, aes(time, N, col=factor(N0))) + geom_point() + theme_bw()

Now I want to fit the logistic population growth model (dN/dt=rN(1-N/K)) with the observed data (df). I searched online and found there were many R packages that could do the work. Now, I could fit the data with the two time series data at different initial densities separately. The following is my code with N0=5 as an example.
library(FME)
# define the logisitic model
logistic.ode <- function(t, N, parms)
{
  r <- parms["r"]; K <- parms["K"]
  dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)
  list(dN)
}
# initial guess of parameter
parms.ini <- c(r = 2, K = 10)

# modcost
mod.cost <- function(parms) 
{
  out <- ode(y=c(N=N0[1]), func=logistic.ode, parms=parms, times=time)
  modCost(out, df[1:21, c("time","N")])
}

# modfit
mod.fit <- modFit(f=mod.cost, p=parms.ini, lower=c(0, 0), upper=c(5, 150))
summary(mod.fit)

I could repeat above procedure for N0=200, but it gives me two different (although similar) estimations of r and K. I am wondering if there are ways to fit logistic population growth model with both time series data simultaneously to have one estimation for r and K because both time series data should obey the same model.

Not familiar with that package. I would have expected one would use the desolve package.

This package is based on desolve package. Could my problem be simply solved in desolve package?

Anyone helps me? Thanks

There were two hits to a search on [r] deSolve fit logistic. If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104342/trying-to-use-the-collin-function-in-the-r-package-fme-to-identify-parameters-an doesn’t answer I’ll take a crack at it in the morning (PDT).

@IRTFM Thanks for your suggestions. I checked the link you shared, however, it does not solve my problem of fitting multiple time series simultaneously. I would be really appreciated if you could give me more help.

Have you checked the parameter starting values. I got better results with a lower vale of K

Sorry. I do not understand why setting of parameter starting values related to my problem. I could have a good estimate of r and K with either time series with N0=5 or N0=200, but they are different. I would like to have just one estimate of r and K using both time series.@IRTFM

With your current data and current differential equation the algorithm obviously diverges. Look at the fit when K=3 as an initial estimate.

I fitted the model with K=3 as initial, the estimate of K is about 86.8.  When I fitted the with K=10 as initial,  it gives me K=99.2. Why such a big difference? if you plot the time series, we can visually see that the K should a number around 100.

I was pointing out that you got a much better fit (narrower confidence intervals and smaller residuals) with different initial parameters. I think you need a different model.
